# request not going through

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

im creating a login page the code im posting doesnt give any errors

```
if request.method == 'POST' and formLogin.validate():
        if formLogin.username_signin == 'admin' and formLogin.password_signin == 'admin':
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

this piece of code gets skipped even when i put admin in box boxes(wtforms) here is the code im using:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'jjjjjjj'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():


    formLogin = LoginForm(request.form)
    error = None

    if request.method == 'POST' and formLogin.validate():
        if formLogin.username_signin == 'admin' and formLogin.password_signin == 'admin':
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            error = 'Please enter right credentials.'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error, formLogin=formLogin)

    return render_template('login.html', error=error, formLogin=formLogin)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

my login.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block head %}
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <form method= post action='/login/'>
                    {{ formLogin.username_signin(class='form-control', placeholder='Username') }}
                    {{ formLogin.password_signin(class='form-control', placeholder='Password') }}
                    {{ formLogin.submit_signin(class='btn btn-primary') }}
                </form>
                <p><strong>Error:</strong>{{ error }}</p>
            </div>    
        </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

Form.py

```
from wtforms import Form,StringField, PasswordField, TextField, BooleanField, SubmitField, validators

class LoginForm(Form):  

    username_signin = StringField('SigninU', [validators.Required('please enter name')])
    password_signin = PasswordField('signinP', [validators.Required('need password')])
    submit_signin = SubmitField('Signin')
```

Like i said everything renders ok and im not getting a error loading my problem is that when i put 'admin' in both boxes instead of redirect me to the home() function it just skips straight to the else statement.

Comment: How did you define LoginForm?

Comment: Just updated post with the LoginForm

Comment: My next step would be to add some print statements for formLogin and request.form to try and troubleshoot what is actually getting assigned there.

Comment: How can i print statement if im running the app from digital ocean

Comment: Did you try including the validation errors in the output? `{{ formLogin.username_signin.errors }}`, etc.

Comment: with a default setup, print statements will go to the logs, however that is setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.data` to access the get_data.

```
if request.method == 'POST' and formLogin.validate():
    if formLogin.username_signin.data == 'admin' and formLogin.password_signin.data == 'admin':
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Comment: Thanks that did it for me!!

Comment: If answer is right , mark this as a right answer for the viewers..@quechon